# Issues with brew doctor (homebrew)

Tags: homebrew

I'm trying to uninstall/re-install my development dependencies via homebrew and brew doctor is giving me the following errors:

```
Robs-MacBook-Pro:~ robcate$ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew     maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for     is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: /usr/local/Cellar isn't writable.

You should probably change the ownership and permissions of     /usr/local/Cellar
back to your user account.
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/Cellar

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
/usr/local/include/node/ares.h
/usr/local/include/node/ares_version.h
/usr/local/include/node/nameser.h
/usr/local/include/node/node.h
/usr/local/include/node/node_buffer.h
/usr/local/include/node/node_internals.h
/usr/local/include/node/node_object_wrap.h
/usr/local/include/node/node_version.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/opensslconf.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-private/ngx-queue.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-private/stdint-msvc2008.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-private/tree.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-bsd.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-darwin.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-linux.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-sunos.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-unix.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-win.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv.h
/usr/local/include/node/v8-debug.h
/usr/local/include/node/v8-preparser.h
/usr/local/include/node/v8-profiler.h
/usr/local/include/node/v8-testing.h
/usr/local/include/node/v8.h
/usr/local/include/node/v8stdint.h
/usr/local/include/node/zconf.h
/usr/local/include/node/zlib.h
Robs-MacBook-Pro:~ robcate$ sudo chown -R $(robcate) /usr/local/Cellar
-bash: robcate: command not found
usage: chown [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] owner[:group] file ...
   chown [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] :group file ...
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to fix these?

Comment: Check your commands: Homebrew tells you to `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/Cellar`, you're doing `sudo chown -R $(robcate) /usr/local/Cellar`. Also, welcome to SO, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some helpful tips on asking good questions.

Comment: Thank you. Glad to be here!

Comment: The warning about `/usr/local/Cellar` not being writable and the `sudo` command that you need to use to fix it requires you to temporarily disable `System Integrity Protection` IIRC. http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/05/disable-rootless-system-integrity-protection-mac-os-x/

Comment: I changed the code from (robcate) to (whoami) and now when I run brew doctor, I no longer receive the first error. Just need to figure out how to remove the Node files